# Ember CLI: Push a custom record in store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

So I have this requirement where when I go to a `whitelist` route, I fetch a list of whitelisted users from an API. My models and serializers are like this:

models/whitelist.js

```
import BaseUser from './base-user';
var Whitelist = BaseUser.extend({});
export default Whitelist;
```

models/base-user.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

var attr = DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr(),
  username: attr(),
  description: attr(),
  profilePicture: attr(),
  followersCount: attr(),
  followsCount: attr(),
  postCount: attr(),
  verified: attr(),
  following: attr('boolean'),
  whitelisted: attr('boolean'),
  blacklisted: attr('boolean'),
  unfollow: followUnfollow,
  follow: followUnfollow,
  whitelist: whitelist,
  unwhitelist: unWhitelist,
  blacklist: blacklist,
  unblacklist: unBlacklist,
  reply: reply,
  getLists: getLists,
  createdAt: attr()
});
```

serializers/base.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var serializeCollection = function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
  payload.records = payload.records ? payload.records : [];
  var users = payload.records.map(function(record) {
    record = record.user ? record.user : record;
    var user = {
      id: record.id,
      name: record.name || record.fullName,
      username: record.screenName || record.username,
      description: record.description || record.bio,
      profilePicture: record.profileImageURLHttps || record.profilePicture,
      followersCount: record.followersCount,
      followsCount: record.friendsCount || record.followsCount,
      postCount: record.statusesCount || 0,
      verified: record.verified || false,
      createdAt: record.createdAt || false
    };
    return user;
  });
  return users;
};

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractFindAll: serializeCollection,
  extractFindQuery: serializeCollection
});
```

serializers/whitelist.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from './base';


var serializeCollection = function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
  /* Here payload is of the form:
   * {
   *    cursor: null,
   *    records: [{
   *      user: {}
   *      friendship: {}
   *    }]
   * }
   */
  var data = this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
  return data.map(function(item) {
    return Ember.$.extend(item, {
      following: true,
      whitelisted: true,
      blacklisted: false
    });
  });
};

export default Base.extend({
  extractFindAll: serializeCollection,
  extractFindQuery: serializeCollection
});
```

Now based on some action, I fetch a new record in the controller like this:

```
actions: {
  addToWhitelist: function() {
    var _this = this;
    Ember.$.get(url).then(function(data) {
      /*
       *The data here is in this form
       * {
       *   frienship: {},
       *   user: {}
       * }
       */

       //What should I do here so that my serializers get called?

    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

What should I do so that I can push a record into my already populated store, such that the serializers will be called, first `whitelist` serializer and then from within it, the `application` serializer?

Answer (score 1):

While ED and I both will suggest you REST API. But sometime you may not have control over your API.

[Ember.Store.pushPayload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) is what you are looking for. This method accept raw JSON data in correct format and push it to your local store models.

A working sample for you may look like

```
actions: {
  addToWhitelist: function() {
    var self = this;
    Ember.$.get(url).then(function(data) {
       self.store.pushPayload(data);
    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition you can add the model name as first parameter, to let Ember Data determine which serializer will be used `self.store.pushPayload('friendship', data);`

Comment: @sushant @jcbvm So yeah I tried this technique and since my model name is `whitelist` I call `self.store.pushPayload('whitelist', data)`. However since my `data` is a normal object with keys `user` and  `friendship`, I get a message on my console saying `Encountered "user" in payload, but no model was found for model name "user"`. I have added comments to show the form of data in my controller and my serializer.

Comment: @KaranThakkar but have to tried exactly i have posted. dont specify model name but use direct push like store.pushPayload(data); Let me know if this works

Comment: @sushant Yes I have. It shows the following error `Assertion Failed: You cannot use store#pushPayload without a type unless your default serializer defines pushPayload`

Comment: @KaranThakkar You are pushing a single record, so I guess it will bypass your collection serializer, so either implement serialization for a single record, or wrap the single record data in a collection format (the payload you described with the cursor and records properties).

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use the `Ember.$.get` to benefit from `ember-data`. You probably wanted to create a record in the following way:

```
actions: {
  addToWhitelist: function() {
    var record = this.store.createRecord('whitelist', { /* your record */ });
    record.save().then(function() {
      // here's after the POST / PUT requests were done
    });
  }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: The problem is that the API is not RESTful. So I can't do a post request. I do a GET request. That saves the data that I want to save on the sever and returns with an object which I want to push to my store (after making it pass through a serializer). Makes sense?

Comment: it does make perfect sense! :) you can use the `DS.Adapter` and override the `createRecord` and `updateRecord` methods. You can just copy&paste the existing e.g. `createRecord` and adjust it to your needs: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.14.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L469

Comment: While this can be a way, sure, do you know if there is some way I can push the raw data that I get from my request into my store and make sure it is serialized on the way?